# Rotating Frames on Curve

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, rotations, algebraic-curves, quaternions

We are describing a  curve with a  moving frame. Figure 1 says about the definition of curve

---

**Figure 1**

[image]

---

**Specifications and Proprieties of the curve**

1. We can make a rotation 3D Matrix  $R(s)_{3 \times 3}$ by arranging the orthogonal directors $d_3(s),d_2(s),d_1(s)$ in column order. Means place $d_3(s)$ as column $1$,$d_2(s)$ as column $2$,$d_1(s)$ as column $3$
2. We can make a vector called Darboux vector at each point

   $\Omega(s)=d_1(s)\kappa_1(s)+ d_2(s)\kappa_2(s)+d_3(s)\kappa_3(s) \tag1$  where $\kappa(s)=\begin{pmatrix}\kappa_3(s)\\ 
       \kappa_2(s)\\\kappa_1(s)\end{pmatrix}$ as mentioned in Figure 1
3. $d_i'(s)=\Omega(s) \times d_i(s),i=1,2,3 \tag 2$
4. From Equation (2) we can derive the  following relationship related to derivative of R(s) as following $R'(s)=[\Omega(s)]_{\times}R(s)\tag 3$ . It means if $\Omega(s)= \left(\begin{array}{c}x (s)\\ y(s) \\ z(s) \end{array}\right) ,[\Omega(s) ]_{\times}=\left( \begin{array}{ccc} 
        0 & -z(s)  & y(s)  \\
        z(s)  & 0 & -x(s)  \\
       -y(s)  & x(s)  & 0 \\
        \end{array} \right)$

   **Question**

   - Assume you are only given the $\Omega(s)$ how can you calculate Rotation 3D matrix R(s)? Is it true that $e^{[\Omega(s)]_{\times}}=R(s)$? If not what could be that relationship

Comment: yes. It's the relationship between the Lie group and the associated Lie algebra.

Comment: @Martial Are you sure? Thanks.. How can I get the proof of it please give me links if you have

Comment: of-course matrix exponent of a skew symmetric matrix is a rotation matrix. But how can I make sure,it suits our case for R(s)

Comment: you can consult this book: http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~murray/books/MLS/pdf/mls94-complete.pdf   ,specially the second chapter.

Comment: I was just writing proof..using Rodriguez rotation formula..Let me look at this pdf too